# "This sentence encodes being false," vs., "This sentence exemplifies being false"

Tags: paradox

Does the liar paradox depend on the admissibility (as meaningful) of, "This sentence exemplifies being false"?

It seems, for Zalta's comprehension principle, that encoding relations are stipulatively definitional; the liar sentence seems as if it is being "defined as" false; so it would seem to disambiguate to, "This sentence encodes being false," instead of the exemplary report. But, "This sentence encodes being false," can exemplify being true just in case that sentence "really does" encode falsity; so the paradox would evaporate.

I don't really think the encoding/exemplifying distinction is enough to solve the liar paradox "just like that." But do considerations like the above testify against the notion of truth-as-a-property in the first place? And if truth isn't a property, then the way the liar sentence is formed (putting truth in predicate, not prosentential, position) seems misguided.

**Corollary:** we can also ask about, "This sentence both encodes and exemplifies being false."

But again, to claim that something exemplifies a property "by definition" seems perilously close to building a boat to Anselm's paradise, at least if the property in question isn't really a property quite so much at all. (Or: if only concrete particulars can exemplify properties as such, then the liar sentence, given as an abstract sentence-type, is not such as could exemplify properties anyway, but only encode them.)

Comment: this is a trying to limit liar's ability to lie. if liar can lie in past only - it is not a paradox, but it is not true liar too.

Comment: @άνθρωπος have you heard of [the revision theory of truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-revision/)? That theory is a special approach to the liar paradox that might be akin to what you're saying (and then is that what you had in mind in your post about this topic?).

Comment: interesting, i ll try to read this manywords, looks close. I have to say that in my native language there are 2 words for truth. One for "local true", and one for "eternal(belief) true". "Local true" can be contested, also any word can be it meaning form and self contra meaning form - it is impossible to make same in English.  Eternal true can't be inverted to a lie in contest, impossible to say - this is a lie, only it is not "eternal true". Also possible to say: i have to say "local true" or it is "local true"; but only possible form: it is "eternal true" - as statement.

Comment: Phrases like "i say the 'eternal true'"~ is possible only in books like Bible (or only Bible) . i image this "eternal true" like holistic object before it becomes divided to dialectic opposites true/lie.
And also it is one more strange thing. In my native language most of words can be inverted to it contra version form, buy adding parts to this word. So, most of words are not true and not lie semantic, or they can be common true semantic, but possible to invert to lie. For "local true" it is possible to make it form similar to lie, so it can hear as lie but with "True" word's root.

Comment: Kristian, i f read some without math proofs. Looks close, but i image this not as T-biconditionals or tri~ but close to graph with cause "vectors', and yes, this method can be used to solve of the 'circularly defined concepts' like paradoxes are.  in my variant 'protospace' was close to M base of L(space) - the T'-language in RTT. Nut is h0, and core is h, but there was also a shell... So, when you have a cat(dead or alive) in the box, and you ll check the cat, you get cat(dead or alive) and empty box. The Truth that the box is become empty now, not cat's biconditional stance.

Comment: or the Truth is M base of L, that is why T in L have biconditional stance